# Método onCreateContextMenu de um Fragment chama o método onContextItemSelected de outro Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho um FragmentActivity que chama seus Fragments em forma de abas (ViewPager).

Em dois desses fragmentos foi implementado os métodos **onCreateContextMenu** e **onContextItemSelected**.

No caso, acontece que quando eu chamo o menu de contexto da lista de um fragmento e seleciono um item, o método **onContextItemSelected** chamado vem do outro fragmento. Logo, qualquer objeto dentro desse método está nulo e gera a exception.

Fragmento 1 - Compra

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Informações adicionais");
    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Itens da Compra");
    menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Formas de Pagamento");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.item_for_listview_consulta_compras);
            dialog.setTitle("Informações Adicionais");
            exibeCompra(arrayCompra.getItem(info.position));
            break;
        case 1:
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.simple_listview);
            dialog.setTitle("Itens da Compra");
            exibeListaItens(arrayCompra.getItem(info.position));
            break;
        case 2:
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.recebimento_forma_pagamento_layout);
            dialog.setTitle("Formas de Pagamento");
            exibeFormaPagamento(arrayCompra.getItem(info.position));
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Fragmento 2 - Venda

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Informações adicionais");
    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Itens da Venda");
    menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Formas de Pagamento");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.item_for_consulta_venda);
            dialog.setTitle("Informações Adicionais");
            exibeVenda(arrayInfoVendas.getItem(info.position));
            break;
        case 1:
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.simple_listview);
            dialog.setTitle("Itens da Venda");
            exibeListaItens(arrayInfoVendas.getItem(info.position));
            break;
        case 2:
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.recebimento_forma_pagamento_layout);
            dialog.setTitle("Formas de Pagamento");
            exibeFormaPagamento(arrayInfoVendas.getItem(info.position));
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

FragmentActivity

```
public class ConsultaTab extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabPagerAdapter myAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    Funcoes.setMenuOpcoesSempreOn(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.act_consulta_cliente_tab);
    setTitle(R.string.title_activity_consulta);

    myAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

    });

    if (extras != null)
        codPessoa = extras.getLong("codPessoaErp");

    for (int i = 0; i < myAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(myAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

Quando eu chamo o menu de contexto do fragmento **Compra** e seleciono um item, por exemplo, "Informações adicionais", o método **onContextItemSelected** executado é do fragmento **Venda**. Só que isso só acontece quando eu faço isso primeiro pelo fragmento Vendae logo após chamo o fragmento Compra. 
O erro que ocorre nesse cenário é um NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem duas formas de lidar com essa situação:

1 - Atribuir um **groupId** diferente para cada grupo de itens de cada menu.

Fragment Compra:

```
menu.add(1, 0, 0, "Informações adicionais");
menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Itens da Compra");
menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Formas de Pagamento");
```

Fragment Venda:

```
menu.add(2, 0, 0, "Informações adicionais");
menu.add(2, 1, 1, "Itens da Compra");
menu.add(2, 2, 2, "Formas de Pagamento");
```

No método `onContextItemSelected()` testar se o item passado pertence ao grupo que se quer tratar

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getGroupId() == 1) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {

            case ....
            case ....
            default:
                return false;
         }
         return true;        
     }
     return false;
}
```

2 - No método `onContextItemSelected` testar se o método `getUserVisibleHint()` retona `true`

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {

            case ....
            case ....
            default:
                return false;
         }
         return true;        
     }
     return false;
}
```

<sub>Adaptado desta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297842/how-to-handle-oncontextitemselected-in-a-multi-fragment-activity) do SOen.</sub>

Comment: Obrigado @ramaral, mas o problema é que ele não vai executar a rotina certa. Somente evita que execute a rotina errada. Ou seja, Se no menu eu seleciono Itens da Compra, ele tenta executar o ContextItem do fragmento Venda (Itens da Venda). Nesse caso eu preciso que ele vá para o próprio contextItem, o que ele não esta fazendo. Valeu

Comment: Você testou a solução?

Comment: Tenha em atenção que deve retornar `false` quando não é o `onContextItemSelected()` pretendido.

Comment: tinha testado sim, mas depois da última dica que funcionou. Não tinha reparado na ``return false``. Muito obrigado. o/